# how to manually run a provisioning script from within the guest?

Tags: vagrant

I would like to manually execute one of my shell provisioning scripts from within the vagrant guest.  I DON'T want to use the `vagrant provision` command to run my script.

Most importantly, I would like to execute using the same permissions and environment that the script would be executed by the shell provisioner.

```
stratosruntime.vm.provision "shell", path: "myscript.sh"
```

I guess the instructions are going to vary depending on the guest OS type, but when sudo is available is this all that is required:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo /vagrant/myscript.sh
```

Or, should I use some other parameters with `sudo` such as `-i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Vagrant uses `sudo -E -H` for executing shell commands:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb#L324